# Detect if a Bytebuffer contains an int or just a byte[]

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I store a column value in DB either as:

1. an empty byte array `new byte[0]`
2. an int value
3. a non-empty `byte[]`

On retrieval of the column value I retrieve it as a Bytebuffer & I need to detect whether it stored an integer, empty byte[], or non-empty byte[].

How do I detect looking at read Bytebuffer, what was stored in it among the above 3 possible options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, after all they are just a pile of bits. You need an external indicator. It can be either a second column or the first bit(s) of input.

If you loaded an empty buffer, empty `byte[]` was stored. If it's not empty, check first bit (or byte for simplicity). Agree that some value indicates that the rest is `byte[]` while other value indicates encoded `int`. Of course prior to that you must also store that indicator.

Comment: may be by looking at the length of byte[] perhaps !?? int should have 4 bytes length, no ? but 4 bytes length wont certainly guarantee if it was an int.. may be or may be not..

Comment: @user01: exactly. So if returned buffer is empty, it was an empty `byte[]`. But 4 bytes don't indicate anything, unless you prohibited `byte[4]`.

Comment: assuming that I limit usage of non empty byte[] cases to just byte[] with length 1 then I can perhaps(!?) clearly detect the one of 3 options ?!

Comment: Yes, if your `byte[]` always holds just one item (so it's basically a `byte`) then you can easily distinguish which type is stored by buffer length: 0, 1 or 4

Comment: Thanks. just the last thing, could you state the correct way of determining the length of  serialized byte[] from ByteBuffer ?